# BufferedImage not found

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm working on image processing with java but the BufferedImage is not resolved and the compiler yells "BufferedImage cannot be resolved to a type".

How to fix that?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.imageio.*;
 
 public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
     BufferedImage img = null;
  }
 }
```

I tried to resolve that issue but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are importing `javax.imagio.*`, but you should be importing `java.awt.image.*`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html